# Leaderboards кастомный UI

Tags: android

Если я правильно понял исходя из доки гугла по поводу Google Play Services, Leaderboards уже имеет свою разметку, мы только запускаем активити. (Пожалуйста, если не так).

**Нужно:**

Получать мое имя, имя ТОП-10 игроков и их и мои очки(одно int значение) и отобржадать их в моей списке.

**Вопросы:**

1. Как задать кастомный layout для Leaderboards
2. Как получить нужную мне инфу в JSONе(или еще чем-то) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `GamesClient` есть метод [`loadAchievements`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#loadAchievements%28com.google.android.gms.games.achievement.OnAchievementsLoadedListener%29).

Импорты:

```
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.achievement.Achievement;
import com.google.android.gms.games.achievement.AchievementBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.games.achievement.OnAchievementsLoadedListener;
```

Сам код:

```
getGamesClient().loadAchievements(new OnAchievementsLoadedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAchievementsLoaded(int statusCode, AchievementBuffer buffer) {
        if (statusCode == GamesClient.STATUS_OK) {
            int achievementsCount    = buffer.getCount();

            [...]

        }
        buffer.close();
    }
});
```

Грузить лидерборды аналогично, используя [`loadLeaderboardMetadata`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#loadLeaderboardMetadata%28com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.OnLeaderboardMetadataLoadedListener,%20java.lang.String%29).

А дальше уже делайте с этими данными что захотите.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. В целом все понятно и то, что мне нужно. Мне вот про sign in не понятно. Нужно ли мне это делать? Если можно объясните по этому вопросу..

Comment: @researcher можете поподробнее? Я не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду)

Comment: В [этом туториале](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-play-game-services-leaderboards--cms-20700)  есть какие-то кнопки SignIn. Как я понял, это для входа в google play services или как-то так..

Comment: @researcher https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin

Comment: спасибо!  Изучу ссылку. Т.е. как я понял - обязательно делать sign in.

Comment: @researcher да, сначала подключение к G+. Потом при успехе уже можно запрос на ачивки слать.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!